# Error: redirect_uri_mismatch message on Google oAuth?

Tags: google-oauth, google-developers-console

I deployed an app to production and i'm getting an error message

> `Erreur 400 : redirect_uri_mismatch The redirect URI in the request, http://codesnippets.azurewebsites.net/auth/google/callback, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs`.

However I added the link to the `URI` along with the link `http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback`. I did the same with the website `http://www.mywebsite.com/auth/google/callback` but when i try to add it i have a message saying that the `app is in production` and the `URL should be https`?
[image]

Comment: Please include the full error.  what url is it saying exactly

Comment: @DaImTo i added the full message

Answer (score 1):

The redirect uri in Google developer console must exactly match the redirect URI your application is calling from.

The easiest way to fix it is to copy the exact url the error message is giving you. If its https you need https if it has a prot you need a port if there is a trailing slash you must include that is as well.

In your case you should add

```
http://codesnippets.azurewebsites.net/auth/google/callback
```

This video will walk you though it. [Google OAuth2: How the fix redirect_uri_mismatch error.](https://youtu.be/QHz1Rs6lZHQ)

I was able to add it to a web client with no issues relating to it not being https.

[image]

Comment: when i try to add `http://codesnippets.azurewebsites.net/auth/google/callback` i have a message saying that the `URL should be https`

Comment: Check update i was able to add it without any issues i am not getting any message relating to it being http.

Comment: i don't know why i can't add it on my side

Comment: YOu need to put your app back in test mode if you want to add a http redirect uri.  Your app has been released to production already you cant have http there.